# How can I convert foreach loop to LINQ lambda

Tags: c#, linq

In this class I define the string method that it navigate through it and make a string according to the number value.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Returnstring (int number)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dictionary.Add(1, "Test");
        dictionary.Add(2, "TestTest");
        dictionary.Add(3, "TestTestTest");
        string somevalue = string.Empty;

        foreach (var simple in dictionary)
        {
            while (number >= simple.Key)
            {
                somevalue += simple.Value;
                number -= simple.Key;
            }
        }
        return somevalue;
    }
}
```

I just want to know how I can convert the foreach loop to a LINQ lambda .

This is the test method that I wrote for the class.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Given_1_when_Returnstring_Then_Should_Return_Test()
{   
    Class1 class1=new Class1();
    string number = class1.Returnstring(1);
    string expectedstring= "Test";
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedstring, number);
}
```

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? What you are asking for is very simple, if only you did some effort.

Comment: Even if you can, you shouldn't. LINQ is designed to be a functional-style framework, and the operations within LINQ statements shouldn't have side-effects.

Comment: And what is the purpose of this code in the first place?  If looks like it repeats the value of the first dictionary `number` times and then ignores the rest of the dictionary.

Comment: Why do you need to use LINQ there?

Comment: There is no foreach method in LINQ (as mentioned above queries shouldn't create side effects) but lets not get ahead of ourselves. **What you can do** instead of using foreach is to **filter the collections** that you have (i.e. lists and dictionaries) to what you need (e.g. `Where`, `Join`, `Select`, etc.) and then perform some action (e.g. `Sum`). There are instances where you do need to iterate with foreach, but most of the time; just filtering your data through LINQ is enough.

Comment: This algorithm is fundamentally flawed.  The first foreach will contain the {1, "Test"} Key Value pair and then you just decrement `number` by 1 until it is zero and you end up with `somevalue` being the string "Test" repeated `number` times (note if number is 0 or less it just returns an empty string).  The remaining iterations of the foreach loop are just going to skip over the while loop.  So basically use of the `Dictionary` and a foreach loop for this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in my understanding that you want the following outputs for the following inputs?

Input: 1
Output: Test

Input: 2
Output: TestTest

Input: 3
Output: TestTestTest

If so, why not just use `somevalue = dictionary[number]` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return string.Join("", dictionary.Take(number).Select(x=>x.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dictionary.Add(1, "Test");
            dictionary.Add(2, "TestTest");
            dictionary.Add(3, "TestTestTest");

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", ReturnResult(3));
        }

        public static Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        public static string ReturnResult(int index)
        {
            return dictionary.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(index)).Select(res => res.Value).First();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether your algorithm is incorrect or not, what it essentially does is repeats the value of the first item in the `Dictionary` `n` number of times (`n` being the `number` parameter passed in).

If this is in fact what you want to do, then you could simply do:

```
string somevalue = string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(dictionary.First().Value, number));
```